# Undo insert query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, undo

I ran an `insert` query on a table in SQL Server by mistake and 100 rows got inserted. I want to undo it but I do not have rollback.

Comment: You will need to delete those 100 rows by a primary key. Run a select query before delete with the same parameter so that you know you are bringing correct rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete, but for future you would need to surround your query in transaction or set such behavior manually.

By default SSMS does auto-commit. To alter this behavior use this:

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF

more here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15